# Php array to MySQL query condition structure

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, regex, filtering

I have following array in PHP:

```
$arr = [1, 3, '4A', '5A', '5C', '2B', '2C', '2E'];
```

Somehow I need to convert this array to a string which look like this:

```
 $filter =     "(id like '1%') OR 
                (id like '3%') OR 
                (id like '4A%') OR 
                (id like '5A%' OR id like '5C%') OR 
                (id like '2B%' OR id like '2C%' OR id like '2E%')";
```

The first character of the array value indicates a unique categorie and is wrapped in parentheses.
In the end I will use this to query the database;

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM list WHERE {$filter}";
```

**Can someone help me converting this array to the correct string ? What is the best method to achieve this ?**

To give you an idea of what I'm trying:
The 'id' column in my database row looks like; 1B2875. Where the first char (1) indicates a categorie and the second char (B) the subcategorie. The given array is a result of a client-side filter request.

Comment: If its not too late I would really suggest normalizing this and using relationships to a `category` and just make the `ID` an auto_increment integer. This setup youre working with now is probably going to cause a lot of hurt later.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions in SQL:

`SELECT * FROM list WHERE id REGEXP '^(1|3|4A|…)[0-9]+$'`

The value inside the parentheses can be generated with the PHP function `implode('|', $filter_strings)`

Note that you should validate and escape the filter strings first to prevent the user input from manipulating the query. The function `preg_quote` is useful here.

Comment: Kudos for thinking outside the box with the MySQL-side regexp.

Answer (score 0):

Populate an array of conditional segments and an array of `%`-wrapped values, then execute your query using a prepared statement (if there are any placeholders in the query) or a standard query (if there are no placeholders).

Code: ([PHPize Demo](https://phpize.online/s/Mp))

```
$array = [1, 3, '4A', '5A', '5C', '2B', '2C', '2E'];

$conditions = [];
$params = [];
foreach ($array as $v) {
    $conditions[] = 'id LIKE ?';
    $params[] = "%$v%";
}

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM list';
if ($conditions) {
    $sql .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' OR ', $conditions);
    $result = $mysqli->execute_query($sql, $params);
} else {
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
}

foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo "<div>{$row['id']}</div>\n";
}
```

While pedestrian, the generated SQL will be:

```
SELECT * FROM list WHERE id LIKE ? OR id LIKE ? OR id LIKE ? OR id LIKE ? OR id LIKE ? OR id LIKE ? OR id LIKE ? OR id LIKE ?
```

If you are not yet enjoying PHP8.2, [there are other ways to bind the parameters/values and execute the query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77597272/2943403).