# Loop over multidimensional array and execute INSERT queries for each pair of subarray of values

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, prepared-statement, sql-insert

I'm looking for a practical way to create a new database record for every 2 content array records with the value of date of the previous sub-array. As for your question: content will always have 24 records (0-23) which if divided should be 12 chunks.

```
[
    [
        'date' => '2018-05-23',
        'content' => [
            [
                'AAAAAA',
                'BBBBBB',
                'CCCCCC',
                'DDDDDD',
                'EEEEEE',
                'FFFFFF',
                'GGGGGG',
                'HHHHHH',
                'IIIIII',
                'JJJJJJ',
                //...
            ],
        ],
    ],
    [
        'date' => '2018-05-22',
        'content' => [
            [
                'KKKKKK',
                'LLLLLL',
                'MMMMMM',
                'NNNNNN',
                //...
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

I need to be able to create a `foreach` loop that will create a database record from 3 variables.

`foreach` #1:

```
$date = $array['content']['date']; //2018-05-23
$headline = $array['content'][0][$key]; // AAAAAA
$content = $array['content'][0][$key]; // BBBBBB
```

`foreach` #2:

```
$date = $array['content']['date']; //2018-05-23
$headline = $array['content'][0][$key]; // CCCCCC
$content = $array['content'][0][$key]; // DDDDDD
```

Until it finishes with the first sub-array and then goes to the second array:

`foreach` #6:

```
$date = $array['content']['date']; //2018-05-22
$headline = $array['content'][0][$key]; // KKKKKK
$content = $array['content'][0][$key]; // LLLLLL
```

I've been trying to group the arrays with `array_chunk` with no success and then I tried to write a small fix to order the array properly with this:

```
if ($x <= 10) {
        if ( $a < 2 ) {
            $a++;
        } else {
            $x++;
            $a = 1;
        }
    $res[$i]['content'][$x][] = ltrim($text);
} else {
    $res[$i]['content'][$x][] = ltrim($text);
    $x = 0;
}
```

Result:

```
[date] => 2018-05-23
            [content] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => AAAAAA
                            [1] => BBBBBB
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => CCCCCC
                            [1] => DDDDDD
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => EEEEEE
                            [1] => FFFFFF
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => GGGGGG
                            [1] => HHHHHH
                        )
```

Which worked for the first array but all the other arrays lost order and were not categorized properly.

Any ideas how this can be created?

Comment: Can you show us the expected output? Is it same as the result that you showed? If yes, can we assume the `initial array` will have even number of records inside `content` ?

Comment: I'm looking for a practical way to create a new database record for every 2 `content` array records with the value of `date` of the previous sub-array.
As for your question: `content` will always have 24 records (0-23) which if divided should be 12 chunks.

Comment: ok, let me try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how your DB structure looks like because you didn't mention, but you can do something like that:

```
<?php
$array = [
    [
        "date" => "date",
        "content" => [["A", "B", "C"]]
    ],
    [
        "date" => "date",
        "content" => [["E", "F", "G", "H"]]
    ],
];

$sql = "INSERT INTO table (content, date) VALUES ";

foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
    $content = $item["content"][0];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($content); $i += 2) {
        $letters = $content[$i];

        if (isset($content[$i + 1])) {
            $letters .= $content[$i + 1];
        }

        $sql .= "('$letters', '$item[date]'),";
    }
}

$sql = rtrim($sql, ",") . ";";

echo $sql;
```

Will output:

```
INSERT INTO table (content, date) VALUES ('AB', 'date'),('C', 'date'),('EF', 'date'),('GH', 'date');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$collection = 
        array
            (
                array
                    (
                        'date' => '2018-05-23',
                        'content' => array
                            (
                                array
                                    (
                                        'AAAAAA',
                                        'BBBBBB',
                                        'CCCCCC',
                                        'DDDDDD',
                                        'EEEEEE',
                                        'FFFFFF',
                                        'GGGGGG',
                                        'HHHHHH',
                                        'IIIIII',
                                        'JJJJJJ'
                                    )
                            )
                    ),
                array
                    (
                        'date' => '2018-05-22',
                        'content' => array
                            (
                                array
                                    (
                                        'KKKKKK',
                                        'LLLLLL',
                                        'MMMMMM',
                                        'NNNNNN'
                                    )
                             )
                    )
            );


function getChunks($data){
    $result = array();
    $length = count($data);

    for($i=0;$i<$length;$i += 2){
        $result[] = array($data[$i],$data[$i+1]);
    }

    return $result;
}

function groupContentByDate($collection){
    $result = array();

    foreach($collection as $each_data){
        $result[$each_data['date']] = array('content' => array());
        foreach($each_data['content'] as $each_content){
            $result[$each_data['date']]['content'] = array_merge($result[$each_data['date']]['content'],getChunks($each_content));
        }
    }

    return $result;
}


echo "<pre>";
print_r(groupContentByDate($collection));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [2018-05-23] => Array
        (
            [content] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => AAAAAA
                            [1] => BBBBBB
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => CCCCCC
                            [1] => DDDDDD
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => EEEEEE
                            [1] => FFFFFF
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => GGGGGG
                            [1] => HHHHHH
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => IIIIII
                            [1] => JJJJJJ
                        )

                )

        )

    [2018-05-22] => Array
        (
            [content] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => KKKKKK
                            [1] => LLLLLL
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => MMMMMM
                            [1] => NNNNNN
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most elegantly, use a parent `foreach()` loop to access the date and the subarray of entries.  Feed a child `foreach()` loop pairs of entries via the returned data from `array_chunk()`.

- From PHP8.2, you can use `execute_query()` to create, bind, and execute a prepared statement in a single operation.
- From PHP8.1, you can pass an array of values to `execute()`.
- Before PHP8.1, bind the variables to the prepared statement before entering the loops and then ensure that the bound variables are assigned by the loops, then execute the statement inside of the child loop.

This will stably and securely insert a new row in the database for each date with pairs of content values.

PHP8.2 Code: ([PHPize Demo](https://phpize.online/s/zp))

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO your_table (date, content1, content2) VALUES (?,?,?)";
foreach ($array as ['date' => $date, 'content' => [0 => $entries]]) {
    foreach (array_chunk($entries, 2) as $pair) {
        $mysqli->execute_query($sql, [$date, ...$pair]);
    }
}
```

PHP8.1 Code: ([PHPize Demo](https://phpize.online/s/Yp))

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO your_table (date, content1, content2) VALUES (?,?,?)");
foreach ($array as ['date' => $date, 'content' => [0 => $entries]]) {
    foreach (array_chunk($entries, 2) as $pair) {
        $stmt->execute([$date, ...$pair]);
    }
}
```

<PHP8.1 Code: ([PHPize Demo](https://phpize.online/s/sp))

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO your_table (date, content1, content2) VALUES (?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $date, $content1, $content2);
foreach ($array as ['date' => $date, 'content' => [0 => $entries]]) {
    foreach (array_chunk($entries, 2) as [$content1, $content2]) {
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```